# Accessing my new Samsung 970 EVO NVMe M.2 drive

Tags: nvme

I recently installed a Samsung 970 EVO NVMe M.2 drive on my Gigaybyte Z390 UD motherboard. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.6. The drive is recognized by the BIOS and shows up (as nvme0n1) when I execute the lsblk command, but it has no mount point, and I can't access it. I have spent too much time looking for an answer on the internet, but most proposed solutions don't work. What can I do to correct this situation?

Comment: You have to create a mount point to mount it. Then only you can access it. You can use gnome-disks to do it.

Comment: Couple of things, 16.04 is EOL in a few months you may want to think about upgrade. You are trying to mount it but have you even partitioned it yet?

Comment: I added Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB to my Z170 system. Updated firmware using ISO from Samsung https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/ , gpt partitioned it in advance for UEFI install with gparted & installed Kubuntu 20.04. Works great. You can also use gparted but must change default partitioning first.
Select gpt under device, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting. or This which also erases drive: `sudo parted /dev/nvme0n1 mklabel gpt`